# proxy_set_header is not working either showing in phpinfo();

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I don't know what else or how to ask Google so I come here.

I have this nginx config file (apache.servers.conf is the name):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.yyy.zzz.235:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

But no matter what, headers are not showing on the phpinfo();

According to this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-16-04-server

> The variables HTTPXREAL_IP and HTTPXFORWARDED_FOR were added by Nginx
>   and should show the public IP address of the computer you're using to
>   access the URL.

I've already replace `mysite` and `xxx.yyy.zzz.235:8080` with the corresponding values

But is not showing on my phpinfo();

This is for a reserve proxy server. Apache and Nginx themselves are working fine but can't say the same about the headers.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you say more detail?what is  "it do not work"?

Comment: So, if I understand your question correctly, since you are using nginx as a reverse proxy, it is hiding the genuine ips and you want them to be passed to your upstream server?

Comment: your configuration looks good to me and you should access the ip address  in this request header `X-Forwarded-For`

Comment: @Mattia Dinosaur what it doesn't work is that the headers are not showing when I do a `phpinfo();`. They are just not there, and everything seems to be working. I don't if I forgot enabling something. @harshavmb Correct, I want to bypass them to Apache so it can make the back-end requests.